# Show operator is not adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have read that

$$T: \ell^1 \to \ell^1, \quad (x_n)_n \mapsto \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n,0,0,...\right)$$

is not an adjoint operator. I know that the dual of $c_0$ is actually $\ell^1 $, but I don't seem to get it since the dual of $\ell^1$ is $\ell^\infty$. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $S : c_0 \to c_0$ is the pre-adjoint of $T$, that is, $S^* = T$. Then $S$ would be the restriction of $S^{**} = T^* : \ell^{\infty} \to \ell^{\infty}$ to $c_0$. It is not difficult to see that the adjoint of $T$ is given by the operator that maps $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to the sequence $(x_1,x_1,x_1,\ldots)$. Now clearly this operator does not map $c_0$ to $c_0$, hence $S$ cannot exist.

Comment: Yes i found the adjoint of T but i was missing the key observation you mentioned. Thank you